# How to route DNS resolver to a different DNS based on the URL hostname?

Tags: dns, hosts, resolvconf

This is why I would like to do:

*Most hostnames -> Resolved by DNS1.

Some hostnames -> Resolved by DNS2 (I don't know IP addresses just the hostname).*

It should look as creating a whitelist/blacklist of websites that should be resolved by another DNS other than the main one. In fact, that's what I'm trying to accomplish.

/etc/hosts is not possible because I might not know the IP of the websites

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a control over the dns records? How are you sure both of them have a dns record of the same host name, and each one of them directs to a different / same host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An interesting approach for such problem would be using `iptables` rules that would redirect DNS query packets based on string patterns in the data section.

Iptables allows creating and managing firewall and routing rules on your machine. It is a vast powerful tool if done right. To make this answer simple - we won't discuss much about the full meaning of the commands. More about iptables here: [IptablesHowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo) (Ubuntu documentation).

Suppose your machine uses the default port for DNS queries (53/UDP), your nameserver address is `8.8.8.8` and you're querying the `askubuntu.com` domain.

When looking at the request packet, we'll notice that the name **length** is **13**, and the **label count** is **2** (askubuntu and com). For `us.archive.ubuntu.com` it would be **21** and **4**.

Now let's try to create a rule that redirects `askubuntu.com` query from the default `8.8.8.8` server to `8.8.4.4` server:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p udp –dport 53 -m string –hex-string “|09|askubuntu|03|com|000001|” –algo bm -j DNAT --to-destination 8.8.4.4:53
```

For `us.archive.ubuntu.com` it would be:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p udp –dport 53 -m string –hex-string “|02|us|07|archive|06|ubuntu|03|com|000001|” –algo bm -j DNAT --to-destination 8.8.4.4:53
```

Overall for the default machine settings the only field that needs to change is the string defined for the `-hex-string` flag. Notice that `|000001|` must always be present at the end of the string (another important part of the DNS request packet).

Another thing to set in mind is that your configuration persists only **until your next boot** (meaning it'll be **removed** once your machine goes off).
You may want to save your configuration using the `iptables-save` and redirect the command output to a file. it is best practice to use the syntax below:

```
sudo iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4
```

To restore your rules from a file, simply use:

```
sudo iptables-restore -n < /etc/iptables/rules.v4
```

**Notice** that the `-n` flag appends rules from your file to any other rules already existing in your iptables. To completely override all your rules with whatever in your file, omit the `-n` flag.

**It might be a little hassle to restore your rules every time**, so I suggest installing the `iptables-persistent` package which does the same for you automatically every boot:

```
sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent
```

The `iptables-persistent` looks for the file `rules.v4` under `/etc/iptables`, so make sure you name it accordingly.